# Get address with public key Ethereum in Rust

Tags: rust, ethereum

I'm trying to get an address with the public key in Rust. I'm using sha3 and `ethereum-types` to archive it but I faced some error. Here is my code:

```
use sha3::{Digest, Keccak256};
use ethereum_types::{H160, H256};

let address = H160::from_slice(Keccak256::digest(&pubkey).as_slice());
```

I got this error

```
panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `32`,
 right: `20`
```

I need first convert to H256 then H160 to make it work because the length of `Keccak256::digest(&pubkey).as_slice()` is 32 not 20.

How can I convert the `Keccak256::digest(&pubkey).as_slice()` len to 20?

Comment: I think the Etherum address format only uses the last 20 bytes of the keyhash so perhaps `Keccack256::digest(&pubkey).as_slice()[12..]`